# Orthogonal invariance of (weighted) Laplacian

Tags: linear-algebra, real-analysis, orthogonal-matrices

It is well-known that if $O$ is an orthogonal map, then $\Delta u(Ox) = \Delta u$ where $\Delta$ is the Laplacian.

Now, let $A$ be a constant invertible matrix, then we define the weighted Laplacian

$$\Delta_A = \langle \nabla, A \nabla \rangle.$$

My question is: Does there exist a function $\varphi_O$ such that $Gf(x):=e^{\varphi_O(x)}f(Ox)$ satisfies for all $f$ but fixed orthogonal $O$

$$\Delta_A Gf(x) = G(\Delta_A f)(x)?$$

Comment: Do you want $\varphi$ to be the same for all $f$ and all $O$?

Comment: @IosifPinelis all $f$ but fixed $O$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\De}{\Delta}$The answer is: not in general.

Indeed, suppose the contrary. Let
\begin{equation}
    A:=\begin{pmatrix}
    0&1/2\\
    1/2&0
\end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}
so that
\begin{equation}
    (\De_A f)(s,t)=\frac{\partial^2 f(s,t)}{\partial s\,\partial t}=f^{(1,1)}(s,t). 
\end{equation}
Let
\begin{equation}
O:=\begin{pmatrix}
    0&-1\\
    1&0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
    g:=\varphi_O, 
\end{equation}
so that
\begin{equation}
    (Gf)(s,t):=e^{g(s,t)}f(-t,s), 
\end{equation}
and the difference between the right-hand side and left-hand side of the equality in question
divided by $e^{g(s,t)}$ is
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    d_f(s,t)&:=\frac{(G(\De_A f))(s,t)-(\De_A(Gf))(s,t)}{e^{g(s,t)}} \\ 
    &=\frac{e^{g(s,t)}f^{(1,1)}(-t,s)
    -\dfrac{\partial^2 f(s,t)}{\partial s\,\partial t}
    \big(e^{g(s,t)}f(-t,s)\big)}{e^{g(s,t)}} \\ 
    &=-f^{(0,1)}(-t,s) g^{(0,1)}(s,t)+f^{(1,0)}(-t,s) g^{(1,0)}(s,t) 
    +2 f^{(1,1)}(-t,s) \\ 
    &-f(-t,s)
   \left(g^{(0,1)}(s,t) g^{(1,0)}(s,t)+g^{(1,1)}(s,t)\right)=0 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
for all $f\in C^1$ and all real $s,t$.

Letting now $f_1(s,t):=s$, $f_2(s,t):=t$, and $f_4(s,t):=t^2$, we get
\begin{equation}
    0=s d_{f_2}(s,t)-d_{f_4}(s,t)=s g^{(0,1)}(s,t),
\end{equation}
so that $g^{(0,1)}=0$ and hence $g^{(1,1)}=0$, which implies $0=d_{f_1}=g^{(1,0)}$.
So, $g$ is a constant, and hence
$0=d_f(s,t)=2f^{(1,1)}(-t,s)$ for all $f\in C^1$ and all real $s,t$, which is absurd. $\quad\Box$